# Suppose $A \subset X$ where $X$ is possibly a metric space, must $A$ also inherit the subspace metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Okay so I don't know what i am overlooking at this simple issue. I was reading the Metrization theorem by Urysohn and the entire idea is focused on constructing a bi-continous one-to-one function that maps onto a subspace (hence this is an embedding mapping onto its image making it a homeomorphism) of metrizable space.

So the stated setup is like this, we have $F: X \to F(Y)$ where $F(Y) \subset W$ and $W$ is a metrizable space like $\mathbb{R}$ (actually it's just the Hilbert Cube).

Now usually when we talk about metrizable subspaces, we begin with the universal space $W$ first and talk about its subspaces, but aren't we doing it backwards and we are exhibiting a subspace that is in a Metric Space? So how do we know that given a subspace of a metric space, it must also contain a metric? It only inherits the topology and the open sets right? And metric induce topologies not the other way around right? I must be forgetting something important.

Comment: Any subset $Y$ of a metric space $X$ is itself a metric space under the same metric (or, more precisely, under the restriction of the metric, which is a function from $X\times X$ to $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$, to the domain $Y\times Y$).

Comment: So it is impossible for a subset $Y \subset X$ to **not** have an induced metric from $X$?

Comment: The restriction of the metric gives the induced topology, not very hard to prove.  In some cases, you might want to get another metric that stilll gives the same topology, but perhaps is better in some ways( complete, bounded, etc)

Comment: Unless otherwise stated the metric applies to all subsets under discussion. Just as when we talk about a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ we typically assume the same metric ($d(x,y) = |x-y|$).

Comment: Okay, sorry I was just confused because we went from subsets to the universal space as opposed the other way that is usually done (universal space, then its subspace inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

The steps are as follows: we consider  the Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ in the product topology.

We can show in general that a countable product of metric spaces in the product topology is metrisable, using a product metric that induces the product topology.

Another general fact: if $(X,d)$ is a metric space (with induced topology $\mathcal{T_d}$) and $Y \subseteq X$ is a subspace of $X$ in the subspace topology $\mathcal{T}_Y$ w.r.t. $\mathcal{T}_d$, then letting $d_Y$ be the restriction of $d$ to $Y \times Y$ defines a metric on $Y$ (quite clear) which exactly induces $\mathcal{T}_Y$. This is probably what you ask about in the title of the post.

So the above 2 facts tell us that when we are in the class of metrisable spaces (so spaces whose topology can be induced by a metric in the space) are closed under the usual (general topological) operations of countable products and subspaces.

So if we show for some space $X$ that there is a map $F:X \to [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $F$ is a homomorphism between $X$ and $F[X]$ then $F[X]$ is metrisable, as a subspace of a countable product of metric spaces (and so $X$ is too).